# Claiming Avios / BA Tier points for a rebooked flight

Tags: loyalty-programs, british-airways

My Icelandair flight to Denver via Keflavik was rebooked by the airline to a direct BA flight when the first leg was delayed (which would have meant missing my connection).

I am a member of the BA Executive Club: can I claim Avios or BA Tier points for this rebooked flight? The BA website has a page to claim missing Avios, but this requires a ticket number which I don't have (it's not on the boarding pass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will receive Avios and tier points for any BA operated flight.

This is a reasonably common occurrence when transferred to another carrier during irregular operations and usually allows you to double dip. You can claim original routing credit for the loyalty programme you intended to fly, and retro-credit for the loyalty programme relevant to the carrier you did fly.

Contact BA with any flight information you have. You may be requested to send in a copy of your boarding pass. If you have a problem on the contact line to BA, there is also a contact on flyertalk who has often been responsive for various unusual requests. The flyertalk contact is BAMissingAvios.

Comment: Thanks, @Berwyn. This is the correct answer. I just needed to ring BA to get the ticket number and then claim through the Executive Club website.

Answer (score 2):

It will really depend on the company goodwill... I don't think they have any obligation in that case to award you Avios. The issue is that the ticket was bought by Icelandair. I guess they have agreements between companies to buy tickets at a discounted rate but then, things like loyalty points are most likely not in the scope...

If I were you, I would try directly with BA. Explain them the situation and ask them. Maybe they will do something as you are loyal customer to them. You'll probably need to call them as the form won't allow you to submit your request due to missing ticket number.

Good luck!

Comment: As the other answer says, this procedure is actually pretty routine and once I had my ticket number I got my Avios without any special goodwill being directed my way.